# How to use python rx's replay?

Tags: python, system.reactive, replay

I want to be able to use the replay operator on a stream that already happens to be a BehaviorSubject.
Essentially, I want the print subscription to receive the emissions that were sent beforehand: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I tried to make the observable hot with `.subscribe()`. Also, I do understand that making the source be a `ReplaySubject` would solve the problem, but that's not an option for me.

Unlike most languages, Python's `rx v3.0` uses the pipe command to chain operations - such as `replay()` or `ref_count()` or `publish()` - instead of the usual '.' chain. Here is a link to what the pipe command is: https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#pipe-based-operator-chaining

I am pretty sure that the issue has something to do with the 1st argument that I gave to replay(): `lambda x: x`.

```
import rx.subject
from rx import operators as op

stream = rx.subject.BehaviorSubject(0)
replayable_observable = stream.pipe(op.replay(lambda x: x, buffer_size=100))
replayable_observable.subscribe()
stream.subscribe()
for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    stream.on_next(x)
replayable_observable.subscribe(lambda value: print("Received {0}".format(value)))
for x in [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
    stream.on_next(x)
```

I expected to receive `0-10`; or maybe `1-10`. But instead I received `5-10`.

```
Received 5
Received 6
Received 7
Received 8
Received 9
Received 10
```

Comment: Only know Rx.Net. I don't know the pipe operator but my feeling tells me that it causes replay to be reutilized for every subscription onto your replayable_observable. Could you please explain pipe? See how it is done in Rx.Net here: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#Replay

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first argument to `replay` (the `mapper` function) is intended to allow you to chain some more operators on to the source observable after it has been multicast. For example, if you change it from `lambda x: x` to `lambda x: x.pipe(op.map(lambda y: y * 2))` you'll get values that are doubled.

The [docs](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_operators.html#rx.operators.replay) for `replay` appear to be out of date, because the example `mapper` function they give still uses the old style of method chaining rather than the pipe approach. In addition, all of the [tests](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/tests/test_observable/test_replay.py) for `replay` that actually use a non-default value for the `mapper` argument appear to be commented out in this project's GitHub repo, so there are no clear examples of how to correctly use this argument.

What I can say, from looking at the source code, is that when you use `replay` without specifying a `mapper` you get back a `ConnectableObservable` rather than an `Observable`. Connecting this `ConnectableObservable` before values are pushed through the subject correctly buffers the results.

```py
import rx.subject
from rx import operators as op

stream = rx.subject.BehaviorSubject(0)
replayable_observable = stream.pipe(op.replay(buffer_size=100))
replayable_observable.connect()
for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    stream.on_next(x)
replayable_observable.subscribe(lambda value: print("Received {0}".format(value)))
for x in [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
    stream.on_next(x)

# Received 0
# Received 1
# Received 2
# Received 3
# Received 4
# Received 5
# Received 6
# Received 7
# Received 8
# Received 9
# Received 10
```